# MASM: Accessing to global C variable from assembly

Tags: c, assembly, dll, global-variables, masm

I'm writing a program to convert image and compare the speed of processing data in C and assembly. I have 3 projects:

- main project in C
- DLL in C to convert image
- DLL in ASM to convert image

In C DLL header, I simply wrote:

```
#ifdef PROJEKTC_EXPORTS
    #define PROJEKTC_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define PROJEKTC_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

...

extern PROJEKTC_API unsigned int ThreadID;      

PROJEKTC_API void __cdecl funkcjaC(void* Args);
```

and after including this header, I can access variable ThreadID both in main project and C DLL.

The problem starts when I try to do the same in ASM. I tried constructions like `extern ASMThreadID:dword` in .code block, but it won't work.

The error I got: `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ASMThreadID referenced in function _MyProc1`

I have a feeling that it's a matter of 1-2 lines of code, but I can't figure out which instruction should I use.

I link the projects by module definition file in ASM and adding ASM.lib file into the Linker->Input of main project.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Compile the C version of the DLL, have the compiler emit assembly, and look how it's done on our platform? This stuff is implementation-dependent.

Comment: Do you mean Disassembly window? I'm using Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7 64-bit, unfortunately it doesn't shows the assembly for this part of code...  

I mean, in C DLL .c file i have global variable:  
PROJEKTC_API unsigned int ThreadID=0;  
and it works brilliantly. Unfortunately, I don't know how to export variable from ASM to C. Where and how should I declare the variable so that it'll be exported outside the DLL. How to use __declspec(dllexport) in assembly.

Comment: C sometimes adds underscores to the name.  Have you tried just adding the underscore when you declare the variable in asm?  And you do declare it as 'public' in your asm, yes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With small help from old posts in asmcommunity.net, I managed to get it working:

- In .asm file, before .data segment:

`EXTERNDEF C ASMThreadID:DWORD`

- In .data segment:

`ASMThreadID dd 0`

- In .def file of ASM DLL:

`LIBRARY "nameOfProject"
EXPORTS
...
ASMThreadID`

- In main C program header (like global declaration):

`extern __declspec(dllimport) unsigned int ASMThreadID;`

Now it works like a charm.

The 'public' declaration sent me to the right way of searching. Thanks for your help, mate!