# Import DLL variable in MASM

Tags: c++, dllimport, masm

I'm trying to access a variable in MASM that's exported in another DLL. But whenever I try to use it, it winds up generating a `jmp` stub (to reduce the number of dynamic relocations), which is wrong for data. Instead, I want it to point directly to the relocation (i.e. the `__imp_xxx` variable). When I do the same in C/C++, it points to the correct variable. I also tried manually using the `__imp_xxx` variable, but I get link errors (unresolved external symbol).

As an example, in MASM:

```
EXTERN _qwglChoosePixelFormat:DWORD
...
    mov     eax, _qwglChoosePixelFormat
...
```

Visual Studio generates/links `_qwglChoosePixelFormat` as a jump stub:

```
...
_qwglChoosePixelFormat PROC
    jmp     __imp_qwglChoosePixelFormat
_qwglChoosePixelFormat ENDP
...
```

But when I try the same in C/C++:

```cpp
extern "C" DWORD __declspec(dllimport) qwglChoosePixelFormat;
...
    DWORD test = qwglChoosePixelFormat;
...
```

It generates the proper code:

```
...
    mov     eax, __imp_qwglChoosePixelFormat
    mov     [ebp+8], eax
...
```

Comment: ``EXTERNDEF C qwglChoosePixelFormat:DWORD`` See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27028508/masm-accessing-to-global-c-variable-from-assembly

Comment: @BitTickler the question you linked refers to exporting a DLL variable defined in MASM and importing it into C, whereas I'm trying to do the reverse.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91sxd44w.aspx "If name is referenced in the module, it is treated as EXTERN. "