# Accessing C++ variables from masm/x64

Tags: 64-bit, masm

Linking and calling functions from masm are OK, but variables mangled or not can't link from masm/x64.

C++: in a DLL

```
extern "C" 
{
    extern __declspec(dllexport) int TestInt;
}

namespace SOMESPACE
{
    class __declspec(dllexport) MyClass
    {
    public:
        int X, Y, Z;
        
        static int StaticInt;
        
        void Test(void);
    };
    
}
```

Call from EXE: in C++, function call and variable accesses are OK.

```
    TestInt = 789;
    SOMESPACE::MyClass::StaticInt = 123;
    SOMESPACE::MyClass X;
    X.Test();
```

Call from EXE: MASM, function link and calls ok, variables cannot link.

```
.DATA
    EXTERN _TestInt : DWORD
    ; EXTERN TestInt : DWORD  <-- does not work either
    ; EXTERNDEF _TestInt : DWORD  <-- does not work either
    EXTERN ?StaticInt@MyClass@SOMESPACE@@2HA    : DWORD

.CODE
    ?Test@MyClass@SOMESPACE@@QEAAXXZ    PROTO

    call ?Test@MyClass@SOMESPACE@@QEAAXXZ        ; OK, link and runs
    mov eax, _TestInt                            ; Cannot link
    mov eax, ?StaticInt@MyClass@SOMESPACE@@2HA   ; Cannot link
```

Linker says:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _TestInt

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static int SOMESPACE::MyClass::StaticInt" (?StaticInt@MyClass@SOMESPACE@@2HA)
```

but dumpbin /exports on the DLL says both symbols are available

```
1236  4D3 000EBB88     ?StaticInt@MyClass@SOMESPACE@@2HA

1431  596 000EBB8C TestInt
```

and using StaticInt and TestInt in C++ works too. So the DLL isn't the problem.

What's wrong with the MASM code?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27028508/masm-accessing-to-global-c-variable-from-assembly

Comment: The post you pointed to moved the variable from C to assembler and accesses it in reverse from C. I have a lot of variables in C++, mangled, in existing libraries that I have to access in assembler. Thanks for the post anyway.

Answer (score 0):

MASM does not automatically resolve external references to data objects like C++ does.

**TestDLL.cpp**

> cl /LD TestDLL.cpp

```
#include <windows.h>

extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) int TestInt = 42;
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

**main.cpp**

> cl /EHsc main.cpp AsmFunc.obj

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllimport) int TestInt;
    __declspec(dllexport) int* TestIntPtr; // Assume TestIntPtr is accessible by your MASM code
}

extern "C" void AsmFunc();

int main() {
    // Load the DLL
    HMODULE hMod = LoadLibrary("TestDLL.dll");
    if (!hMod) {
        std::cout << "Failed to load DLL" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Get the address of TestInt
    FARPROC ptr = GetProcAddress(hMod, "TestInt");
    if (!ptr) {
        std::cout << "Failed to get TestInt address" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    //  MASM doesn't have a mechanism to automatically find that variable and resolve its address.
    TestIntPtr = (int*)ptr;

    //  Similarly for ptr = GetProcAddress(hMod, "?StaticInt@MyClass@SOMESPACE@@2HA");

    // Call the assembly function
    AsmFunc();

    // Free the DLL module
    FreeLibrary(hMod);

    return 0;
}
```

**AsmFunc.asm**

> ml64 /c /Cx /Zi AsmFunc.asm

```
extrn printf:proc

.DATA
    EXTERN TestIntPtr:QWORD

    szArray db 'TestInt = %d',0ah,0

.CODE
AsmFunc PROC
    mov rax, TestIntPtr
    mov eax, dword ptr [rax]  ; EAX now contains the value of TestInt
    
    mov     rdx,rax 
    mov     rcx,offset szArray
    sub     rsp,20h
    call    printf
    add     rsp,20h   
    
    ret
AsmFunc ENDP

END
```

Running `main.exe` shows the value of the C++ variable:

[image]

Comment: Oh...I linked with the generated .lib 'stub' of the dll, I didn't use LoadLibrary. I should have made it clearer...I was in fact doing more or less what you've done, i.e., create a local pointer variable in the EXE that's addressable via masm and set it up on init to point to the DLL variable, just thought if there is a cleaner way.